# Prevent page to go back on top when selecting a star rating

Tags: css, colors, hover, rating

I found a code to help change stars color as you hover over them. It works like a charm. However, when I click on a star to fix the rating, it sends me to the top of the page. The stars are a little at the bottom of the page so it is very annoying to click on a star and end up at the top and having to scroll back down again. 
The page is not being refreshed. It just sends me to the top. Is there a way to prevent this and allow the user to click on the star and stay on the part of the page where the stars are?

HTML

```
<fieldset class="rating">
<legend>Please rate:</legend>
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the full code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/CGP87/light/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CGP87/884/)**

Hi User2961763

It seems that `top:-9999px;` on `.rating:not(:checked) > input`  causing problem. if you comment or remove this style it will work fine though you also need to take care that it wont affect your other functionality. Hope it Helps

```
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    /* top:-9999px; */
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Another option worth considering is ```top: auto;```